# How to iterate multiple urls in javascript in Chrome console window with timeout

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, webbrowser-control, windows-console

I want to iterate through the URL's who has different php id number at the end and after the execution of one of the URL I want to print some data like say "Next" or something and wait for 7 seconds and then execute the next URL by incrementing the PHP Id value.

This all I am trying to execute in the Chrome Console window using Javascript.
Any doubts please do ask and thanks for any help in advance.

```
for(j=1000;j <= 1010; j++) {
  this.document.location = "http://website.com/page.php?id=" + j;

  setTimeout(console.log('Next'), 7000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info... Then how if I open a new window and run on that window and close that window and again open a new window with new php id... Will that work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        var idVal = getParameterByName("id");
        if(idVal== "" || idVal == null){
            idVal = 1000;
        }else{
            idVal++;
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Next");
            this.document.location = "http://website.com/page.php?id=" + idVal;
        }, 7000);

    </script>
```

Comment: Above function will first check id parameter in url.. If it do not exists then it will assign to 1000 and if exists then we increment it and call the document.location after 7 second.

Comment: Thanks for the code but its not working... actually it is not looping through the URL's I want to loop through it bro...

Comment: It will loop through the urls... change the demo URL with original URL. We have test it at local and it is working

Comment: I had replaced the demo with the original one... But it is incrementing only by 1 and again stopping. and I am running this is console window I have removed the lines script tag and I had run it but not working. :(

Comment: I have added the code here : http://ourdemoapp.com/Script/index.html And it is working fine

Comment: Hey Yeah it is working I see... But I don't know why it is not working here. I have opened the console window ctrl + shift + j and I have run the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing it in an iframe. This will iterate over the list, waiting for the current url to resolve.

```js
const urls = [
  "https://css-tricks.com"
, "http://stackoverflow.com"
, "https://scotch.io"
, "http://ramdajs.com"
, "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe"
, "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp"
]

const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
iframe.height = window.innerHeight

const iterate = (urls, timeout = 500, ii = 0) => {
  return e => {
    if (ii < urls.length) {
      setTimeout(() => iframe.src = urls[ii++], timeout)
    }
  }
}

iframe.addEventListener('load', iterate(urls, 500))
```

```css
html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<iframe src="http://nettuts.com" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort bro.. But I am sorry I am unaware of iframe... Can you please give me more detail or demo how to use it and solve this problem It would be really great help...

Answer (score -1):

```js
const urls = [
  "https://css-tricks.com"
, "http://stackoverflow.com"
, "https://scotch.io"
, "http://ramdajs.com"
, "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe"
, "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp"
]

const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
iframe.height = window.innerHeight
var ii = 0;
const iterate = (urls, timeout = 500) => {
  return e => {
    if (ii < urls.length) {
      setTimeout(() => iframe.src = urls[ii++], timeout)
    }
  }
}

iframe.addEventListener('load', iterate(urls, 500))
```

```css
html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<iframe src="http://nettuts.com" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Instead of taking ii into function call please make it global

Comment: why? it's in a closure

Comment: When function execute after 7 second then the scope of ii variable get change. It is working fine at : http://ourdemoapp.com/Script/

Comment: I think you need to read and understand the code to realise why that doesn't matter.

Comment: Have you checked the demo URL

Comment: Yes, have you clicked "Run code snippet"? Please describe the exact problem with having a non global iterator variable. if you look at the code it is a function that returns a function which you guessed it create's a closure. Having a global variable is bad practice that could clash with other variables, considering that this is an iterator and it's asynchronous you will have problems. Try putting a loop using `ii` as the iterator directly after this code.

Comment: I checked the demo URL but I need to execute it in console window once the page gets executed I need to gather data and print it by using console.log and again iterate and again gather data and print by console.log... So this is the exact scenario.. I need to do this for different php id URL's